# Swiftにて、TableViewから遷移した複数ページ内でページめくりさせたい。

Tags: swift, swift3

Swift3にて、TableViewのセルによって、画面遷移先をそれぞれ振り分けた場合、その遷移先のページ（複数）同士だけでスワイプでページめくりをさせて、また、各遷移先のページからは、NavigationControllerの戻るボタンなどからTableViewのページに戻れるようにしたいのですが、やり方が分からないです。

初期画面はTableViewのあるVCで、NavigationControllerをEmbedしております。
TableViewのセルからそれぞれの遷移先に画面遷移させるところまではできています。

Swift勉強中であまり難しいことは分かりませんが、教えて頂けると大変助かります。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

TableViewから遷移する先として、 [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller) を使いましょう。
親のUINavigationControllerにpushする形で遷移すれば、戻るボタンなども通常どおり使えます。

`transitionStyle` を `.pageCurl` にすればページめくりのアニメーションも使えます。

※ ただし、ページめくりはナビゲーションバーと見た目の相性が悪いです。そもそも最近はあまり流行っていないように思います。

UIPageViewControllerの使い方は以下のページなどを参考にしてください。

- [Qiita - 【決定版】UIPageViewControllerの使い方（Swift）](https://qiita.com/Takeshi_Akutsu/items/dbf54df8e8a50e8ed5be)